# I need to colorize a specific item on my html

Tags: html, css

I want to colorize the button with number 25 > 25
like a number 15 > 15

Can you help me? Thanks.

I need to color a specific item on my html but I can't.
I need to color a specific item on my html but I can't.
I need to color a specific item on my html but I can't.
I need to color a specific item on my html but I can't.
I need to color a specific item on my html but I can't.

```
<div class="calc">
<div id="display" class="display">0</div>
<div class="keypad">

<div class="keys-row first-keys-row">
<div class="key clear-all">AC</div>
<div class="key show-display">80</div>
<div class="key show-display">85</div>
<div class="key show-display">90</div></div>

<div class="keys-row">
<div class="key show-display">20</div>
<div class="key show-display">25</div>
<div class="key show-display">30</div>
<div class="key show-display">35</div></div>

<div class="keys-row">
<div class="key show-display">5</div>
<div class="key show-display">10</div>
<div class="key show-display">15</div>
<div class="key calculate">=</div></div></div></div>

<style>
.calc {
color: #fff;
width: 400px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #302d2d;
border: 10px solid #302d2d;
border-bottom: 5px solid #302d2d;
border-radius: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;}

.calc .display {
font-size: 40px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
background-color: gray;
border: 10px solid gray;
border-radius: 10px;
color: black;
height: 80px;}

.keys-row {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
margin-bottom: 10px;}

.keypad .keys-row .key {
background-color: #999191;
font-size: 35px;
text-align: center;
width: 95px;
line-height: 75px;
border-radius: 50px;
margin: 0 5px;
cursor: pointer;
user-select: none;}

.keypad :first-child :nth-child(1){
background-color: black;}

.keypad .keys-row .key:active{
background-color: #a5a5a590;}

.keypad :last-child :nth-child(4){
background-color: lightseagreen;}

.keypad :last-child :nth-child(4):active{
background-color: #17807a;}

.keypad :last-child :nth-child(3){
background-color: #b22222;}

.keypad :last-child :nth-child(3):active{
background-color: #801818;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.keypad div:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(2) {
    background: #b22222;
}
```

- The first `div:nth-child(2)`, is to select the second DIV inside `.keypad`
- The second `div:nth-child(2)`, is to select the second button of the DIV

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I can reference all.

Comment: The button with 25 is

`.keypad div:nth-child(4) div:nth-child(2) {background: #b22222;
}`

Answer (score 0):

this can be an other option:

```
        <div class="keys-row second-keys-row">
        <div class="key show-display">20</div>
        <div class="key show-display">25</div>
        <div class="key show-display">30</div>
        <div class="key show-display">35</div></div>
        
        <div class="keys-row third-keys-row">
        <div class="key show-display">5</div>
        <div class="key show-display">10</div>
        <div class="key show-display">15</div>
        <div class="key calculate">=</div></div></div></div>

<style>
        .keypad .keys-row.second-keys-row .key.show-display:nth-child(2){
        background-color: red;}

        .keypad .keys-row.third-keys-row .key.show-display:nth-child(3){
        background-color: red;}
</style>
```